# Assigning textbox values to session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, textbox, auto-update

I cant understand whats wrong with this simple code.

Page load starts with filling textboxes with session data,

```
    tbgiris.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["giris"]);
    tbmail.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]);
    tbisim.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["isim"]);
    tbgrup.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["grup"]);
    tbkimlik.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["kimlik"]);
    tbadmin.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["admin"]);
```

This works fine. Then, I edit those textbox values manually in browser, and call the button function which must simply update the session values with given data in textboxes, and re-write textboxes as a confirmation,

```
    Session["giris"] = tbgiris.Text;
    Session["mail"] = tbmail.Text;
    Session["isim"] = tbisim.Text;
    Session["grup"] = tbgrup.Text;
    Session["kimlik"] = tbkimlik.Text;
    Session["admin"] = tbadmin.Text;

    tbgiris.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["giris"]);
    tbmail.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]);
    tbisim.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["isim"]);
    tbgrup.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["grup"]);
    tbkimlik.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["kimlik"]);
    tbadmin.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["admin"]);
```

This is where I fail. Session values stay same, does not get updated. If I change the session value to a static value in button function, like,

```
    Session["giris"] = "test string";
```

it works fine, updates the session and textbox. But if I try to get values from textboxes, code behaves like I have never changed texts of textboxes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> code behaves like I have never changed texts of textboxes

You did, but then you changed it back.

In the ASP.NET WebForms page lifecycle, `Page_Load` is executed on a post-back *before* event handlers are executed.  So what's happening is:

- Set the `TextBox` value in `Page_Load`
- Display the page
- Change the value
- Submit the page
- Set the `TextBox` value in `Page_Load` (this is the problem)
- Get the `TextBox` value in event handler

In order to prevent your `Page_Load` logic from executing on a post-back, you'd wrap it in a conditional:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

That way the code will execute only when the page is first loaded, so you're not over-writing the updated values on every post-back.

Answer (score 0):

put this inside because when page post back it assign the same old value in the session to textboxes thats why you are getting the old values.

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
    tbgiris.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["giris"]);
    tbmail.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]);
    tbisim.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["isim"]);
    tbgrup.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["grup"]);
    tbkimlik.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["kimlik"]);
    tbadmin.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["admin"]);
    }
```